# How to pass 'self' parameter of one class to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to incorporate matplotlib into tkinter by having multiple frames. I need to pass the entry inputs from `StartPage` frame to update the plot in `GraphPage` once the button in `StartPage` is clicked. Therefore, I'm trying to bind the update function of `GraphPage` to the button in `StartPage`, but the update function requires `self` parameter which I can't get. Here's the set up of my code right now:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class PeakFitting(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
    '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

       # Setting up frame and widget

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry1.grid(row=4, column=1)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                         command=self.gpUpdate())
        button3.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

    def gpUpdate(self):
        graphPage = self.controller.get_page("GraphPage")
        GraphPage.update(graphPage)
        self.controller.show_frame("GraphPage")

class GraphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.a = fig.add_subplot()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")


    def update(self):

        startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")
        self.iso = startpage.entry1.get()

##Calculation code for analysis not needed for question

app = PeakFitting()
app.mainloop()
```

for `gpUpdate` function in `StartPage`, I tried to pass `graphPage` as `self`, but got an Error that it's a `NoneType`. I also tried `GraphPage.update(GraphPage)` but get 'type object 'GraphPage' has no attribute 'controller'' Error.

I'm very sorry if my explanation wasn't clear, but I am very new to Python and has been struggling for weeks now to pass the entries to GraphPage class after the button is clicked but still can't do it... Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Thank you so much!!!

EDIT: I guess my main problem is how to call a function of one class in another class, because I don't know what the `self` parameter should be :(

EDIT2: Changes to code thanks to suggestion:

```
def gpUpdate(self):
    self.parent = PeakFitting()
    self.grpage = GraphPage(self.parent.container, self.parent)
    self.grpage.update()
    self.controller.show_frame(GraphPage)
```

However, when I input something in the entry and hit the button, the `self.iso` field still remains empty...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between two frames in tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

Comment: @ParvizKarimli That post tells me how to switch between frames which I already did... It was the calling a function of one frame from another frame that I have problem with :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
GraphPage.update(graphPage)
```

You call the method on the class itself. You need to create an instance of that class and then call the `update` method with a parent and a controller, for example:

```
self.grpage = GraphPage(parent, controller)
```

And then:

```
self.grpage.update()
```

Aside from this, you have another problem `in button3`- change this:

```
command=self.gpUpdate()
```

to this:

```
command=self.gpUpdate
```

without parenthesis. This is a function that you pass to the button, and will be invoked upon button click.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did get rid of the errors, which is just fantastic!!! However, now that the `update` function in `GraphPage` runs, for some reason the `self.iso` field still remains empty string even if I've input a string before hitting button. What could be wrong? Thank you so much!!! (I've put update of code up on edit section :) )

Comment: Did you change `command=self.gpUpdate()` to `command=self.gpUpdate()`?

Comment: If you meant to `self.gpUpdate`, then yes I have. I just don't know what the problem is at this point :(